# Pull to refresh is not working properly if bottom half of the screen is listview

Tags: android, pull-to-refresh

Pull to refresh is not working properly if bottom half of the screen is listview, when I try to pull it is not smooth, it is jerking.

[image: this is the layout].

Comment: are you using footer  ?

Comment: I am not using any footer. If u see the layout the listview is starting from Date, above that is general layout.

Comment: It is not working when we populate the data in list view.